# prefer-color-scheme: Operating System vs User Agent, which take precedent

Tags: css, themes

As the title said, if User-Agent's theme and Operating System's theme are different, which one will be in effect?

I think the modzilla web dev does not talk about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme). It only said the prefer-color-scheme depends on User-Agent or Operating System.